# How to find the last email with an attachment in an email thread

Tags: gmail, attachment

In a very large email thread, is there a way to find the last email with an attachment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the emails are grouped by conversation, click on the respective conversation, and then click on circle with a number in the middle (on hover, the number will turn in two arrows), to partially open all the messages.

[image]

After this, scroll down to the last message that has a clip icon next to its date.

[image]